# Substitute a key text in a MS Teams message with a matching URL

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

I have a MS Teams chat where issues are discussed.

My issues are mentioned like abcd-12 and I want them to appear on the chat as a link to the issue.

The links should appear with their proper code, ABCD-12, and the URL is https://link.to/my/bugtracker/ABCD-12.

The regex part is easy enough. /(ABCD-{0,1})(\d{2,3})/gmi should match the incoming messages, and the substitution https://link.to/my/bugtracker/ABCD-$2 should build the URL.

My question is: how to make this automagically in MS Teams?

First there is a placement issue. When and where such a substitution should be called. I think that the best place would be for new messages, after they are posted. The message is changed by the editor as part of the sending action or by MS Teams itself, as a MS Power Automate flow or something.

But then this leaves me with two paths with no clear exit:

1. How can I make the editors on other clients do the thing? Surely they would need to add something  to do this. How would it be done, and what kind of permissions are needed for this?
2. What Power Automate flow would do this programmatically?

I haven't found a place in the web that answers this, which seems like an easy and common thing. I also don't want a bot replying to the message with the link, as this would pollute the chat.

I looked around MS Power Automate and found the "when keywords are mentioned" trigger, but from then on, I am at a loss. I have absolutely no idea how to set a scope (new messages or messages already in the chat) or how to use a regex in the "keywords to search for" group.

Comment: Could you please check this [blog](https://www.tachytelic.net/2021/04/power-automate-regex/) which explains about regex matching?

Answer (score 0):

Could a Message Extension work for your flow perhaps? That means it would be one of those little buttons at the bottom of the chat window, that the user could use to type or search for the relevant issue, and it would then control what gets entered into the final message.

This post explains what the types of Message Extensions exist in Teams (there are 3 types- you'd be wanting specifically a Compose Box extension) - I'm linking to a specific image in the page just to give an idea of where it appears in Teams, but if it works, read the article itself of course: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/design/messaging-extension-design#message-extension-management-menu